# Beep from a C application on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have an existing application in C that needs to produce a beep. I tried using `printf("\a")` and `printf("\7")` but no sound is produced. Currently, I am using the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sys/ioctl.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <linux/kd.h>

int freq = 2000;
int ms = 1000;
int fd = open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY);
ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, (int)(1193180/freq));
usleep(1000*ms);
ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, 0);
close(fd);
```

Based on [beep.c](http://www.johnath.com/beep/beep.c) and several other forum answers. Still, it produces no sound.

I've also done the following steps (as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228096/terminal-bell-doesnt-ring)) to solve the problem to no avail:

> Run gconf-editor and if the desktop | gnome | peripherals | keyboard |
>   bell_mode setting is present then change it from off to on
>
> Run dconf-editor and if the org | gnome | settings-daemon |
>   peripherals | keyboard | bell-mode setting is present then change it
>   from off to on
>
> Add pactl upload-sample
>   /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg to the file
>   ~/.xprofile (you need gnome-control-center-data for glass.ogg)
>
> Add [ "$DISPLAY" ] && xset b 100 to the file ~/.bashrc

Also:

> uncomment the following in /etc/pulse/default.pa:
>
> load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg
>
> load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system

I saw a separate thread with the alsamixer solution but there doesn't seem to be a 'PC Beep' option that I can see.

What else can I try to produce a beep from my C program?

Comment: You really need to add error checking to your code. Is the `open` of `/dev/console` succeeding? Are you running the program with permission to write to `/dev/console`? Does sound work at all on the machine?

Comment: One thing to confirm is that echo -e "\a" actually causes a beep on your platform. You might have some other, system issues affecting your results... like the BIOS has the beep turned off, or something to that effect.

Comment: `echo -e "\a"` works on my machine

Comment: I put in a check for `fd = open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY)) == -1` as per beep.c, and it IS getting the error that it cannot open the /dev/console. Would this also prevent `printf("\a")` from working?

Comment: the header file: `iostream` is a C++ header file , not a C header file!  please either correct to `stdio.h` or change the tags from "c" to "c++"

Comment: does `sudo modprobe pcspkr; echo -e "\a"` make a sound?